# Lombok-Plugin not working in several IntelliJ IDEA setups

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

I tried to use Lombok via Plugin in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2 on MacOS and Ubuntu 18.04. I followed the [Homepage instructions](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij) but I couldn't get my editor to recognize the Lombok Annotations in either of the IntelliJ setups.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: Annotation Processing is already enabled.

Comment: Of course it's hard to say without more information but in general in my experience this has to do with "annotation processing" not being enabled in IntelliJ. To enable: Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> check "Enable annotation processing".

Comment: Also check you have all required dependencies added in project. If issue remains provide a sample project to check.

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel: Sorry, I forgot: I already enabled annotation processing simply by checking the checkbox and without any further settings made.

Comment: @Andrey: How exactly do I do that? And why should I? The instructions do not mention any further manual configurations...

Comment: Do you have Lombok plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Did you also add it as a Plugin?? I faced the same problem that was resolved after adding it as a plugin in intellij

Comment: Yes, I actually installed ONLY this plugin via IntelliJs plugin marketplace. What else should I have done? Like I said, I followed exactly the homepage instructions...

Comment: Also add it as a maven dependency.            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.12</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>